# When selecting all radio buttons with knockout, it doesnt recognize the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHj5X/76/) clarifies things And my `selectAll` method with pure jquery.

```
self.selectAll = function( data, event){
  $(".dataQueryRadioBtn").each(function() {
    $( this ).prop('checked', true );
  });
}
```

When you click on one of the radio buttons and then on *Click Me* a message shows you the number of the clicked radio button. When you do the same now first clicking on Select All it doesn't show every radio button. Only those you clicked yourself. Why is that so?

Comment: your `self.selectAll` not in your `ViewModel` and `selectAll function` just check the checkbox, not push value into `self.selectedTags` here is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/2tjv40f3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Knockout has no way to know that the `checked` property of your `<input>` has been changed because you only registered a `click` handler for each.

You can solve this easily by [triggering](http://jsfiddle.net/eHj5X/77/) the `click` event:

```
$(".dataQueryRadioBtn").prop('checked', false).click();
```

But generally, when you're in the realms of your `viewModel` (just like in your `selectAll` method) you shouldn't rely on DOM elements (it's the elements that should rely on your view-model, not the opposite) to fetch data but rather explicitly change the observable value.

And in your case:

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;

    // ...

    self.allPossibleTags = []

    self.selectAll = function(data, event){
        self.selectedTags(self.allPossibleTags);
    }
}

// upon document.ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.allPossibleTags = $('.dataQueryRadioBtn').get().map(function(elm) { return elm.value });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHj5X/82/)